# Sort the day names elements in order for mapped values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to sort the mapped values for week day names.

I have an array `defaultDays` which contains daynames.

`defaultDays` could be `["friday", "monday", "thursday"]` or `["monday", "thursday"]` (day names could be in any order)

based on the values in `defaultDays`, I create time picker in the same order as per values in `defaultDays` order.

How can I sort below elements to show day names in order? Help is appreciated!

```
<Row className="marginBottom15">
        <Row className="marginBottom10">
          <Col>Store Hours:</Col>
          <Col className="marginLeft15">
            <Checkbox.Group
              defaultValue={defaultDays}
              onChange={onCheckBoxChange}>
              <Checkbox value="monday">Monday</Checkbox>
              <Checkbox value="tuesday">Tuesday</Checkbox>
              <Checkbox value="wednesday">Wednesday</Checkbox>
              <Checkbox value="thursday">Thursday</Checkbox>
              <Checkbox value="friday">Friday</Checkbox>
              <Checkbox value="saturday">Saturday</Checkbox>
              <Checkbox value="sunday">Sunday</Checkbox>
            </Checkbox.Group>
          </Col>
        </Row>

        {defaultDays.map((day) => {
          return (
            <Row className="alignBaseline flexWrapper marginTop5">
              <Col className="width100px">{toTitleCase(day)}</Col>
              <Col className="marginLeft15 ">
                <Form.Item
                  className="fullWidth"
                  name={`${day}StartTime`}
                  label="Start Time">
                  <TimePicker
                    defaultValue={_commonTime.startTime}
                    onChange={(time) =>
                      onTimeChange(time, `${day}StartTime`, `${day}`)
                    }
                    minuteStep={15}
                    format={timeFormat}
                  />
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
              <Col className="marginLeft30">
                <Form.Item
                  className="fullWidth"
                  name={`${day}EndTime`}
                  label="End Time">
                  <TimePicker
                    defaultValue={_commonTime.endTime}
                    onChange={(time) =>
                      onTimeChange(time, `${day}EndTime`, `${day}`)
                    }
                    minuteStep={15}
                    format={timeFormat}
                  />
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          );
        })}
      </Row>

      function onCheckBoxChange(checkedValues) {
        setDefaultDays(checkedValues);
}
```

This is how it looks currently:
[image]

**you might be wondering how this list is created unordered in first place?**

answer : I am showing all 7 checkboxes in proper order.
When user clicks on any checkbox it created the first day row with time pickers.

e.g. user clicks friday checbox first, it created time pickers for friday and so on...

I need to rearrange below rows maps elements according to day order.

checkbox order has nothing really has to do with below order.

Here is sandbox link -
https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-haze-i5vdy?file=/pages/index.js

Comment: Can you please also create demo of this on jsfiddle or codesandbox or any of your comfortable environment so that it can be easier to debug?

Comment: This will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892674/sort-array-of-days-in-javascript

Comment: here is sandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-haze-i5vdy?file=/pages/index.js

Answer (score 0):

```js
const order = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']
defaultDays = ['friday', 'tuesday', 'monday']
defaultDays.sort((elem1, elem2) => {
  return order.indexOf(elem1.toLowerCase()) - order.indexOf(elem2.toLowerCase())
})
console.log(defaultDays);
```

Comment: how do I use sort with map ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-haze-i5vdy?file=/pages/index.js

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Reactjs user but I would write something that gets all the Checkbox elements, then prepends them inside the Checkbox.Group holder based on the order of your array. Something like this:

```
let checkboxes=document.querySelectorAll('Checkbox');
for (let d of defaultDays) {
  for (let c of checkboxes) {
    if (c.getAttribute('value')==d) {
      c.parent.prepend(c);
      continue;
    |
  }
}
```

I haven't tested this -- you should write the code yourself. But in principle, since prepending *removes and replaces* the element, going through the array and prepending should rearrange the checkboxes based on the array order.

Comment: I am not trying to rearrange the checkboxes. I am trying to rearrange timepicker rows actually.