# How can I sort an array that contains the day of the week?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Suppose I have an array like such

```
const week = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
```

How would I go about if I wanted to sort the array depending on the current day. Say, if today's friday, the week array will be like this

```
["Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"]
```

Comment: Easiest way would be just to construct a new array.  Slice the current array at the index for the current day until the end, and then append the days that were before the current day index to that new array

Comment: Or append the array to itself, and then slice from current day index to current day index + 7

Comment: That's not sorting, it's just rotating.

Comment: ... or calculate the index to read according to the current day.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892674/sort-array-of-days-in-javascript
Please take a look at this

Answer (score 0):

You can find the start from the index of the current day and then loop to push all elements to the result array in the correct order.

```js
const week = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
const res = [];
const day = "Friday";
for(let i = 0, j = week.indexOf(day); i < week.length; i++, j = (j + 1) % week.length){
  res.push(week[j]);
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Hardcoding the day, doesn't really address the "current day" concern